# Get external metadata with python script streamripper for win32

Tags: python

Hey I'm using streamripper for win32.
I've setup a sample python script to display dummy metadata.
Streamripper just plain doesn't pick it up. I've put it in the same format as the example:
http://streamripper.sourceforge.net/history.php

It just doesn't work for me.
Anyone know how to fix?

```
import time
while 1:
    print 'TITLE=thisname\nARTIST=thisartist\n.\n'
    time.sleep(10)
```

I put the script in the root directory of streamripper.
Tried linking by using:

```
script.py
c:/program files/streamripper/script.py
c:\\program files\\streamripper\\script.py
```

example:

```
CMD-->
cd c:/program files/streamripper
streamripper http://stream-114.shoutcast.com:80/smoothjazz_skyfm_mp3_96kbps -E script.py
```

nothing works...

Answer (score 1):

the correct usage is:

```
streamrippper URL -E python "path to script"
```

must add python to environment variables of windows
perl conveniently already does on win32 install, but python doesn't

```
streamripper URL -E perl "path to script"
```

Also in python, you must flush the output immediately
This works:

```
import time
import sys

while 1:
    print 'TITLE=thetitle\nARTIST=theartistname\n.'
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(10)
```